# Recently executed SQL not in V$SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Under what circumstances does a select query not appear in the V$SQL view?

For example, if I run this:

```
select /*findme*/ * from T ...
```

And then immediately afterward run this:

```
select * from v$sql where sql_text like '%/*findme*/%';
```

Under what circumstances would I get no rows returned?  And under those circumstances can I force a query's info to be recorded in V$SQL?

Comment: Are you running on a cluster?  Did you try to select from `gv$sql`?

Comment: Your user has his own object V$SQL

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak News to me, but apparently yes.  Can you add as an answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are on a cluster?  Or did you just try `gv$sql` and it worked?  Because that could also mean @MichaelPiankov guessed it.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak It is a RAC.  Although I'm interested in finding out how a user can have his own object V$SQL too.  Researching that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > Under what circumstances does a select query not appear in the V$SQL view?

One situation is on a Real Application Cluster (RAC).  In such environments, `V$SQL` will only contain the library cache of the current node.  To see the library cache across all nodes, select from `GV$SQL`.