# Executed SQL query not appearing in V$SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have the anonymous statement below that ran successfully

```
set serveroutput on
declare

    l_certificate_number number;

BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(certificate_number)
  INTO   l_certificate_number
  FROM   xx_tbl
  WHERE  pnd_type_code = 1
  AND    establishment_id = 1
  AND    period_name = 1;

  dbms_output.put_line('Generate Certificate num ' ||to_char(l_certificate_number));
  
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        l_certificate_number := 0;
        dbms_output.put_line('Generate Certificate num ' ||to_char(l_certificate_number));
END;
```

and successfully showed the output:

```
Generate Certificate num 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I want to find the SQL_ID but it's not appearing in any of the following queries:

```
select  *
from    v$sql
where   sql_text like '%SELECT MAX(certificate_number)%';            

select  *
from    v$sqlarea
where   sql_text like '%SELECT MAX(certificate_number)%';            

select  *
from    dba_hist_sqltext 
where   sql_text like '%SELECT MAX(certificate_number)%';
```

I'm pretty sure the statement executed, since the output was shown.

I've already tried the solution in [Recently executed SQL not in V$SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114515/recently-executed-sql-not-in-vsql) but it's also not found in `GV$SQL`

Any idea where I can find the SQL_ID?

Comment: The PL/SQL you show is not good, there's no ';' at the end of select... And are you looking for the sql_id of the SELECT or of the full PL/SQL?

Comment: Perhaps somebody or some automated system such as scheduler or job flushed shared pool before issuing those queries from data dicionary views...

Comment: @gsalem thanks for that. i've added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL statements in PL/SQL blocks are transformed before they are executed and stored in GV$SQL. You must search for the transformed queries and consider the following ways the text will change:

1. **Case** The statements are converted to uppercase, except for the literals.
2. **White Space** Consecutive white spaces are combined into a single space.
3. **INTO** The `INTO` or `BULK COLLECT INTO` sections are removed.
4. **Bind variables** PL/SQL variables used in SQL statements will be converted into something like `:B1`.

Your query was already avoiding issues #2, #3, and #4 because it was only looking for a small snippet of the code with no bind variables. Since case is the only issue, adding a `LOWER` or `UPPER` should return the results:

```
select *
  from gv$sql
 where lower(sql_text) like lower('%SELECT MAX(certificate_number)%')
       --Only include SELECT statements and not the PL/SQL block.
   and command_type = 3
       --Prevent this query from returning itself.
   and sql_text not like '%QUINE%';
```

There are many weird issues that can happen when querying from `GV$SQL`. Queries may show up multiple times because of different instances, execution plans, and other reasons. And the queries will age out or may be manually removed by `alter system flush shared_pool;`.

If you need the query to be stored in the shared pool exactly as written you can run the statement with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.